# How to send image properties to server using url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I send data only. Here is my data:

```
export const cabin = {
    name: '001',
    maxCapacity: 2,
    regularPrice: 250,
    discount: 0,
    image: './cabins/cabin-001.jpg',
    description:
      'aaaaaaa',
}
```

I send this data using `axios`:

```
async function createCabins() {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:3005/cabins",{
    cabin
  }).catch(error=>{
    if (error) console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

On server I my post route this:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const data = await Cabins.create({...req.body, image: req.file.path})
        res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json(error)        
    }
})
```

Error here I send only image url. How to send image props to server.
I try many ways like these:

```
import cabin1 from './cabins/cabin-001.jpg'
```

or

```
image: require(''./cabins/cabin-001.jpg')
```

These don't help me.

Comment: are you develop both api and front end at same time?  you should do api first, ensure it works. you can use postman to send to api https://www.postman.com/downloads/ then, when you know it work, can develop the front end

Comment: I develop both. I know and testing using postman. If I use postman it is work correctly but only upload many data using frontend

Comment: OK, wonderful. so which properties do you want to submit? is your issue sending the props or trying to get the props from the image?

Comment: please keep in mind that your API should be solid, you should be able to simulate everything you would like to do using POSTMAN

Comment: I am trying get props image by url

Comment: here not problem a backend or frontend. Only I want get image props by url. create function for return object like when select image from input element type="file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be serializing your object before sending through axios. so you should use JSON.stringify() function.

Please confirm that the end point is correct: here, you are specifying /cabins but in your server code, it is just /

I would also suggest that you RENAME the endpoint as single, so change cabins to cabin

```js
await axios.post("http://localhost:3005/cabins",{
    JSON.stringify( cabin )
  })
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for accepting this answer!